# move_uploaded_file no me salta la excepción si no encuentra el directorio de destino

Tags: php, apache2

tengo una duda con la función 'move_uploaded_file' de PHP. Si por ejemplo el archivo que quiero subir es incorrecto o no existe me salta la excepción, pero si no encuentra el directorio de destino no lo hace.
En el archivo error.log de apache si me aparece un warning:

> [Thu Oct 05 20:08:40.412764 2023] [php:error] [pid 6811] [client 127.0.0.1:54056] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught ValueError: Path cannot be empty

En este caso cambie el valor de $destino por unas **""** como ejemplo. Os pongo el código.

```
if (!move_uploaded_file($nombreFoto, $destino)) {
            throw new Exception($mensaje, 0);
        }
```

¿ Abría que modificar el nivel de error en el ini.php ?

Answer (score 2):

```
if (!is_dir($directorioDestino)) {
    throw new Exception("El directorio de destino no existe.", 0);
}

if (!move_uploaded_file($nombreFoto, $destino)) {
    throw new Exception("Error al mover el archivo.", 0);
}
```

De esta manera, primero verificas si el directorio de destino existe con is_dir() y, si no existe, lanzas una excepción con un mensaje descriptivo. Luego, si el directorio de destino es válido, intentas mover el archivo con move_uploaded_file() y lanzas una excepción si este proceso falla.

Comment: Hola @Luis, gracias por contestarme. Ya conocía la función 'is_dir', la uso ya hace mucho, pero lo raro que según  la documentación de PHP : Si filename es un archivo subido válido, pero no puede ser movido por algunas razones, no sucederá ninguna acción, y move_uploaded_file() devolverá false. Adicionalmente, se emitirá un aviso. Osea da que pensar que si no lo mueve por que no encuentra el directorio también debería devolver 'false' y a mi no me lo hace. En cambio si pongo unas " " a $nombreFoto si me devuelve un false.